# apache spark 1.4 python get started error on mac

Tags: python, macos, apache-spark, pyspark

I have installed Spark 1.4.0 on my Mac and am following the [Quick Start guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html).

For Interactive Analysis with the Spark Shell with Python, when I try to start running the following in the Spark directory I get the following error:

```
./bin/spark
SyntaxError : invalid syntax.
```

After talking to two others that had the same experience, I am hoping to get some help/answers from the StackOverflow community.

Comment: Shouldn't you be running `./bin/pyspark` ? If I try ./bin/spark I get  No such file or directory

Comment: To run python interactive shell, run pyspark. Before you run the command once check if you have that file in bin directory of your spark folder.

Comment: try /bin/spark-shell  or ./bin/pyspark

Comment: @MattMcKnight - you are correct, it should be ./bin/pyspark.

Comment: @pradyumnad - that file is NOT in my bin directory.  I'm learning on the fly and will figure out how to do it.  Thanks!

Comment: fixed!  installed using Homebrew.  Thanks for the comments!